# Accessing AWS instance through IAM role via Putty

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS console.

1. I have created a Instance in ubuntu server and key pair
2. I have created a IAM Role (Developer and Administrator)

I can able to login using IAM role in AWS console. And also Using Putty i am able to login with localhost:  ubuntu@Public DNS value.. Once i logged in i want to access AWS instance using IAM role (Developer and Administrator) in putty.But its not logging in.

Is it possible IAM role to be used in AWS instance.

```
Using username "ubuntu".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Mon Dec  1 05:36:34 UTC 2014

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           97
  Usage of /:   12.1% of 7.74GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 7%                IP address for eth0: 172.31.23.230
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

57 packages can be updated.
31 updates are security updates.

root@ip-172-31-23-230:/home/ubuntu# login
ip-172-31-23-230 login: B00017
Password:

Login incorrect
ip-172-31-23-230 login: root@ip-172-31-23-230:/home/ubuntu# login
ip-172-31-23-230 login: B00017
Password:

Login incorrect
```

Comment: http://utkarshsengar.com/2011/01/manage-multiple-accounts-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : no.

IAM roles and SSH key pairs are two different mechanisms that apply at different levels, for different users and different type of authentications.

IAM roles are containers for permissions on AWS API. A role describes a set of permissions on AWS services, such as EC2, S3, DynamoDB etc ... The entity that will assume the role (a person or an EC2 instance for example) will temporary receive the authorisation to perform the actions described in the role's permissions.

You can use IAM roles to control who can access the AWS API (start a machine, create a load balancer, create a network etc ...) but IAM roles do not help to control who can connect to your Operating Systems.

To control access at the operating systems level, (on linux) AWS requires you to generate a pair of cryptographic RSA keys and to upload your public key on AWS. When your linux instance starts, a process will install a copy of your public key in a (operating system) user directory (~/.ssh/authorized_keys). Username is operating system specific (ubuntu on ubuntu, ec2-user on Amazon Linux and RedHat)

IAM is not involved when managing users at operating system level or permissions to connect to your operating systems.

More details about roles is available http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/WorkingWithRoles.html